# jQuery href attribute starting with /{tag_

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I need to remove all the links in my document that start with "/{tag_" or "{tag_"

so far I have `$("a[href^='/{tag_']").remove();` but it's not working,

I also had

```
   $("a").each(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                if(href == '') { // or anything else you want to remove...
                    $(this).remove();

                }
                $("a[href^='/{tag_']").remove();
            });
```

And I have tried `$(this).attr("href^='/{tag_'");` also not working, Any ideas?

Thanks Tara

Comment: It works for me in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yQypx/ You don't really want to be doing the $("a[href^='/{tag_']").remove(); inside the each loop though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $("a[href^='/{tag_']").remove();
});
```

That works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/tKapr/1/

Comment: The loop is kind of redundant, isn't it? The remove() works on the whole set of selected objects anyway, afaik.

Comment: True, but included it because OP was having issues. (+1 to you)

Answer (score 3):

Not much point in using the each.

Can just do:

```
$("a[href^='/{tag_']").remove();
$("a[href^='{tag_']").remove();
$("a[href='']").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `match`

```
$('a').each(function() 
{   
    if ($(this).attr('href').match("^/{tag_"))
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution using `match()` - +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a').each(
            function (){
                if($(this).attr('href').match('^tag_')){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        );
    })
</script>
<a href="tag_me">tagme</a>
```